Testing constraints of pydantic models
Say I have a model
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Book(BaseModel):
  name: str
  description: str = Field(min_length=1, max_length=64, pattern="^[a-z]+$")

I would like to write unit tests ensuring the model has properly been defined.
To be clear, I trust pydantic to be able to properly validate what is defined, I don't trust myself nor my coworkers to always properly define the model constraints, which are our business requirements.
To tests these constraints/requirements I'm tempted to instantiate the model with wrong values, then catch the ValidationError, then check the content of the error to make sure it's the expected error.
Something like:
def test_book__error_invalid_description():
  with pytest.raise(ValidationError) as err:
    Book(name="toto", description="123")
  assert "pattern_error" in err.value.errors # not working, that's just the idea

However I find this very ugly and difficult to maintain. Also, I believe this is mainly testing pydantic itself and just a little bit my requirement (not even all the cases for the pattern requirement are tested here).
I would rather test the presence of the constraints themselves, but I cannot find a clean and concise way of doing it.
Here is what I tried:
from annotated_types import MinLen, MaxLen

def test_book__validation_constraints():
  assert Book.model_fields["name"].is_required()
  assert MinLen(1) in Book.model_fields["description"].metadata
  assert MaxLen(64) in Book.model_fields["description"].metadata
  assert # no idea how to assert pattern

Is there a better way of doing this ?
Do you think it is overkill to test this sort of requirements ?

Personally I would test the behaviour, not whether some field attribute has the expected value.  I want to test that (say) my string's length is within a given range.  I don't care how the constraint is declared, I care that I'll get an error if I try to create it with a value outside the range.

casually, pytest and unittest also have string matching in their exception context manager (pytest.raise(..., match=r"regex") and .assertRaisesRegex respectively)

@snakecharmerb IMHO testing that an error is raised when the constraint is invalid means  testing pydantic itself, which is not what I want. It is also quite cumbersome to write every case ensuring a good coverage of the constraints.

@ti7 thanks, but I don't want to tinker regexes ensuring I have the proper errors raised by pydantic.

I would have added tests to validate that the configuration of the model is correct. E.g. if it's important that the strict validation is set, then I would test that no extra fields are allowed. Or in your case, where a field has a regex-constraint. Then it's important that the regex is correct, since regex' are easy to get wrong. So I would instantiate one base-object, then change the field I want to test for the different scenarios. That would allow me to validate only that field.

Personally, I'd just test this implicitly by testing the code that exercises this model. Testing serializers/models like this is a bit too "unit-y" for my taste. My thinking in this direction is largely informed by this line of thinking: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/write-tests
If it was me, assuming this is validating the body of an api request, I would just write tests that exercise the api with valid and invalid values. To me, that's the "best bang for your buck" in terms of what these tests really add to your application.
If you really want unit tests for your models, the original test (ie with pytest.raise) is the right direction imo. Your second approach is testing pydantic internals. What if pydantic changed the way that they store this information internally, but the model still works? Your tests will break, but your code will still work. I think this is a dark path to sadness that you should try to avoid.
Generally we want to write tests to increase our confidence in our application. The opposite of confidence is fear. In your case, the fear we are trying to allay is that whatever part of your code is relying on this model for validation will not work. Assuming this is validating the body of an api request, the "bad thing that could happen" is that someone will send a request and it will incorrectly succeed or fail validation. It's not "bad" if pydantic changes their implementation. It's bad if the validation stops working. Your first approach succeeds here, your second approach does not.
To your question "how to make sure a string's max-length is define to 12 without creating test cases with strings longer than 12": in my opinion you should not do this. What is the value-add here? What is so bad about having a test with a long string? What kind of complexity are you adding to your codebase to avoid that? That added complexity may in fact reduce the confidence we have in our application! Be kind to grug because grug is you https://grugbrain.dev/#grug-on-complexity
Tests should be simple, not clever. Think about what you are afraid of breaking, and test it directly.

I'm not sure I like the idea of relying on integration tests to test such detail, but I can't find a better way or doing this.
To your comment "That added complexity may in fact reduce the confidence we have in  our application", I disagree as I find a test like assert model.property.max_length == 12 simpler, more focus and easier to maintain than setting up the property to a long string and testing that an validation error is raised.
